# How to solve these equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have come across two equations while deriving some trigonometric identities.  How to obtain the values of $x$ and $y$ when $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$ are known values?
 $$ ax + by = c$$
$$ ay - xb = d$$
Please pardon me if the question seems trivial.
Any suggestions will help.

NOTE: Thank you for various solutions. The obvious solution of elimination did not come in my mind. Sorry for this basic question.

Comment: Try to eliminate one variable ..

Comment: Can't I add or subtract the equations and then compare LHS and RHS?

Comment: Write it as $\,(x+iy)(a-ib)=c+id\,$. Granted, this is not necessarily the most obvious way to solve it, but then you posted no hint of what you have tried, if anything at all.

Comment: @drake I recommend just multiply first eqn by $b$ and second by $a$ and add them to get value of $y$ and similarly $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use substitution to find $x$ and $y$.

$$ax + by =c $$ 
$$ y = \frac{c - ax}{b}$$

then you would substitute the $y$ equation to solve for $x$

$$ a(\frac{c - ax}{b}) - xb = d$$

Then once you solved for $x$, you can solve for $y$!

For example, let's say $a = 1, b = 2, c =3  , d= 4 $

Your two system of equations would be

$$ \tag{1}  x + 2y = 3 $$
$$ \tag{2} y - 2x = 4 $$

Solving $(1)$ for $y$:

$$y = \frac{3-x}{2}$$
Then sub the $y$ equation into $(2)$, we have:

$$ \frac{3-x}{2} - 2x = 4 $$

then $$\color{red}{x = -1}$$

sub that back into $(1)$ and solve for $y$

$$ -1 + 2y = 3 $$
$$ \color{red}{y = 2} $$

I hope this help!

Comment: This covers the case $b\not=0$. Otherwise if $a\not=0$ you also may solve the system. Then again the solution is unique. What happens if also $b=0$?

Comment: Well obviously I was giving him an example to reinforce his intuition.  There are three cases when solving a system of linear equations:  infinitely many solutions, a unique solutions, or no solutions.   A system has no solution if the equations are inconsistent, a unique solution when it is consistent and the number of variables is equal to the number of nonzero rows,infinitely many solutions when it is consistent and the number of variables is more than the number of nonzero rows in the rref of the matrix.

Comment: In this case if $b=0$, there would be no solutions.  OP is clearly just getting started with linear algebra, hence I didn't include that explanation, but rather keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

If you have learn about matrices, the problem is equivalent to the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ - b & a \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix}$$

Consider taking inverses of a particular matrix.

Comment: I barely think Op knows about this. But this is the way

Comment: You are right, I haven't studied matrices yet, but thanks.

Comment: I see, in that case either substitution or King Tut's solution by elimination most likely is the expected approach.